# How many relays can I control arduino/raspi at the same time?

Tags: arduino, led, relay, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm thinking about a project using arduino or raspberry pi (I don't mind working with one or another). The thing is that in my project, I have to control at least.. 50 leds/relays and there will be activated at least 10 of them at the same time.

The easy way is using gpio directly with the leds/relays, but of course, neither arduino nor raspi have so many gpio outputs.

I was thinking on using some demultiplexers, but if I use them, then I may loose the ability to activate at least 10 at the same time..

For example: My project has 50+ leds/relays, and now I want to activate `[1, 7, 12, 17, 21, 26, 32, 41, 44, 48]` at the same time. One second after, I want to activate `[6, 12, 15, 27, 29, 31, 35, 44, 47, 50]` and all others will remain disabled.

Thanks in advance!